# Building dynamically a submenu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, submenu

Having the following structure:

```
<div id="block1">
   <ul class="category">
      <li>Comedy</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="block2">
   <ul class="category">
       <li>Comedy</li>
       <li>Drama</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The unordered list `category` is generated with a php `foreach()`, and in some blocks the `ul` may contain 1 `li` and in others 2, 3 or X `li`, so I need to convert those extra `li`s in a submenu with the first `li` on top.

- My question is, how to select the rest of the `<li>` that's after the first one? Because once I have the rest of the `li`, I can wrap them inside another `ul` and build the submenu.

I can use the following code to filter the lists with more than an option, but what then?

```
    $('.categories').filter(function() {
        if($(this).children("li").length > 1) {
            console.log($(this).text());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wrapAll` method.

```
$('ul.category').each(function(){
  $('li:gt(0)', this).wrapAll('<ul/>')
})
```

Comment: Maybe `li:gt(0)` will be slightly faster.

Comment: @VisioN Yes, but `:not()` is not _slow_ too.

Comment: @undefined Just from the point of *2 selectors vs. 1 selector*.

Comment: @VisioN Updated, just for you _:)_.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the `li` elements after the first one use `.slice()`

```
$(this).children("li").slice(1);
```

then you can work with those elements to do whatever wrapping you need